# NavigationController not displayed when used along with TabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ios4, uitabbarcontroller

In my iphone app, i have a navigation Controller and a tabBar Controller.

The TabBarController has three tabs. In the second and third Tab the NavigationController are added to the viewControllers.

**Problem :**

In third tab viewController shows the NavigationBar but the in second tab viewController doesnot display navigationBar.

**Things I have tried and checked:**

1) I checked that all the connections in IB are done properly

2) I checked the size of frame for the view. It doesnot overlap the navigationBar.

3) I also tried using **self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;**

But still it does not show the navigationBar in the second tab.

What should I do?

Please Suggest

Please Help

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops!!! a big mistake on my part.I did not check the checkbox for "show navigation bar" in inspector for NavigationController. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

We can't do much without looking at your code.

Assuming your `TabBarController` is properly connected in Interface Builder, you'll need something similar to this:

```
UIViewController *firstView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *secondView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *thirdView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *firstNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondView];
UINavigationController *secondNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:thirdView];

self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:firstView, firstNav, secondNav, nil];
```

Of course, have every view released afterwards.

Comment: That is already done but still the problem is the same. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm thats a problem i faced too.

If you look at your  IB file ,you'll see that you can do a bit of tweaking and acheive it.
i'll post details as soon as i get time.

Comment: check if you have ticked the show navigationBar checkbox in Inspector in IB